# Integral $\int_t^T\frac{1}{\phi-\psi e^{-\gamma(T-s)}} \operatorname d \!s$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am having trouble solving the following integral:

$$
\int_t^T\frac{1}{\phi-\psi e^{-\gamma(T-s)}}ds
$$

Maybe there's something obvious I am missing, my approach so far has been to use a substitution equal to the denominator, which allows me to then use partial fractions, but that doesn't get me very far, are there any neater approaches?

Update: Let $u=\phi-\psi e^{-\gamma(T-s)} \implies s=\frac{1}{\gamma}\left[log\left(\frac{\phi-u}{\psi}\right)+t\gamma\right]$

Therefore: $ds=\frac{-du}{\gamma (\phi - u)}$

Upper Bound of Integration:  $\phi-\psi$

Lower Bound of Integration: $\phi-\psi e^{-\gamma(T-t)}$

and the integral becomes: $\int_{\phi-\psi e^{-\gamma(T-t)}}^{\phi-\psi} \frac{-du}{u\gamma(\phi-u)}$

Comment: I think your substitution idea is correct, can you write down what you got after the substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding indefinite integral, with constants combined and renamed, is
$$\int \frac{ds}{P + Q e^{Rs}}.$$

Substituting $u = P + Q e^{Rs}$ gives $du = QR e^{Rs} ds$, but rearranging and substituting gives $$ds = \frac{1}{QR} e^{-Rs} du = \frac{1}{QR} \left(\frac{Q}{u - P}\right) du = \frac{du}{R(u - P)}.$$

Back-substituting, the indefinite integral is

> $$\int \frac{1}{u} \cdot \frac{du}{R(u - P)} = \frac{1}{PR}[Rs - \log(P + Q e^{Rs})] + C.$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute
$$
u = e^{-\gamma(T-s)} \\
du = e^{-\gamma(T-s)} \cdot (-1)^2 \gamma ds = u \gamma \cdot ds \\
ds = \frac{du}{u\gamma }
$$

Then you have

$$
\frac{1}{\gamma} \int_{e^{\gamma(t-T)}}^1\frac{du}{u(\phi-\psi u)}
$$

which should be easily solvable with basic methods.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\int \frac{1}{a-e^x}dx=\int \frac{1}{e^x(a\cdot e^{-x}-1)}dx=\int \frac{e^{-x}}{a\cdot e^{-x}-1}dx=-\int \frac{1}{a\cdot t-1}dt=$$

$$=-\frac{1}{a}\ln|a\cdot t-1|+c$$

where $\ a $ is a constant and I put $\ e^{-x}=t$